# Cannot view attached file in BitBucket PR comment via curl from Jenkinsfile

Tags: curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am trying to attach a html file to bitbucket PR comment via curl command from Jenkinsfile. Here is the curl command I am using - `curl -k -u $username:$pass -X POST $URL -H \"Content-Type: multipart/form-data\" -F "file=@/<obsolute_path>\index.html\"`. With `--verbose` I see no errors in curl execution but I am not sure if the file is attached to bb.
BB PR comment generated

[image]

When I click index.html I see `com.atlassian.bitbucket.NoSuchObjectException`

[image]

Jenkins console showing curl `--verbose` logs -
[image]

When I access that attachment endpoint it throws HTTP 405 PAGE ERROR
On `--trace -` I can see the content of my html file but can't figure out where is the getting uploaded/attached in bb. `--trace` log below

[image]
[image]

My Bitbucket version is 7.8.1 and on API 1.0

Comment: I tried your commands, and I got the same behaviour (Bitbucket 7.20.0). I assume you are following this guide: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-enclose-file-to-pull-request-comment-via-rest-api-952073003.html I didn't get the responses that they mention in the guide.

Comment: @eeijlar Yeah I followed the same guide... I doubt if API version has to be 2.0... not sure though. [This](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/What-API-version-does-my-corp-BB-server-is-on/qaq-p/1847283) is my post in Atlassian Community on the same.